# Jquery: Attaching click event with all anchor in table head and tfoot

Tags: jquery

here is my sample table. i just do not include tfoot html here.

```
<table class="test-table">
<thead>
<tr class="webgrid-header">

    <th scope="col">
    <a href="http://localhost:13562/page1">ID</a></th>

    <th scope="col">
    <a href="http://localhost:13562/page1">First Name</a></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
```

### i used this jquery code but no luck.

```
$(document).on('click', '.webgrid-header .webgrid-footer a', function () {
    alert('Click on link');
});
```

where i made the mistake.

Comment: use `'.webgrid-header a, .webgrid-footer a'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like below. Use `.webgrid-header a, .webgrid-footer a` instead of `.webgrid-header .webgrid-footer a`

```
$(document).on('click', '.webgrid-header a, .webgrid-footer a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Click on link');
});
```

Comment: i used that but not working. basically a dynamic script is there in page which call server side function when click on link. may be that script is firing first and that is why your script is not working. anything can do?

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamic script`? Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the redirection on click of `<a>`. @Mou

Comment: if i use event.preventDefault() then ajax call will stop may be. i want to call my function when link will be clicked and then ajax call will begin but ajax related code is not in my hand rather it is injected in my page automatically. so what is your suggestion.

Comment: `ajax` call should not stop for `e.preventDefault()`. @Mou

Comment: how to suspend ajax call for few moment. i have seen if i show alert box then it is getting suspended and when click on ok button on alert then ajax call start.

Comment: Better ask a new question for this issue. @Mou

Answer (score 0):

Use `.webgrid-header a, .webgrid-footer` a instead of `.webgrid-header .webgrid-footer a`

Check [**multiple-selector**](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.webgrid-header a, .webgrid-footer a', function () {
    alert('Click on link');
});
```